# Hosting a Website using Google Drive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-drive-api

When I host my website on google drive, the theme doesn't appear.

It is just html

Here is the website

https://7976f312c67e0a4a5adb779c37c5416abb33a345.googledrive.com/host/0B9FUHfF3ih1LS0tVaG1OQUZ3TzQ

ps:it is a bootstrap theme

Comment: check a dev console there are a bunch of errors

Comment: See [ask] - your code should be posted here, not on some external site. Posting only a link to some external web site for us to debug for you is of no value to any other user, and your question becomes meaningless once the problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Google Drive: how to share a folder as a website: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/publish-site**

None of your dependent files are being found.

The CSS and JS references don't resolve on 7928d7c5809550dde86880a4bd11a7d7f1dc7dc6-31a3bb7233aac18ebc3c5aaed9de6058f5cfb745.googledrive.com

*Edit after your comment:*

The Google Drive reference still doesn't resolve.  Just glancing quickly at the resources in your html, content in subdirectories are not found.

Comment: thank you for your answer, All the files are in the same folder look https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B9FUHfF3ih1Lfm0xV3EzUjI1RUFic19fVG9jcTIyWHg3ZUN0b1NfbDFQTmoxVTZjd2RHdUE&usp=sharing

Comment: I was wrong with other link here is the right one https://7976f312c67e0a4a5adb779c37c5416abb33a345.googledrive.com/host/0B9FUHfF3ih1LS0tVaG1OQUZ3TzQ

Comment: I updated my answer with a link to how Drive folders should be shared.

Comment: Thank you ,you are the best, Problem solved.I was hosting the html file intead of the folder.

Comment: You should select my answer as the accepted one! :)